# Is there plastic wrapping center at Stuttgart Airport?

Tags: airports, fragile-luggage, stuttgart

Is there any web site from where I can receive information of where I can find plastic wrapping centers at airports? I will be taking an early morning flight (7:00) from Stuttgart and I would like to know if these wrapping centers would be open at around 5:30 on a Sunday. In some airports there are people at these wrapping centers who help wrap the luggage for you. In some airports, it could be automated.

In short, where, what are their timings and what is the cost?

Airport - Stuttgart

Size of baggage - cabin sized trolley with intention of checking in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [official website of Stuttgart airport (STR)](http://www.flughafen-stuttgart.de) lists a [service they call Wrap&Fly](http://www.flughafen-stuttgart.de/reisende-und-besucher/shops-dienstleistung/dienstleistungen/dienstleistung/?id=1543).

Opening hours according to the website are Monday through Sunday 5.30am to 6pm.

The service is located at Terminal 3, Level 3.

Comment: I cannot comment on the cost at the moment - I will try to update the post next time I fly through STR.